# How to display all taxonomy term fields when adding node in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to make form to post advert in newspaper and want to let user select style of future post and show how it will be printed. So i create taxonomy vocab. "style" with name, sample image and max. characters to this type.
Next i'm creating field taxonomy term relation in advert content type.

Now i need to show in adding form not just radios or select with titles but title, sample image and other fields from taxonomy.

I think i need to use `hook_form_alter` so i use `mymodule_form_ad_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)` but what i can't understand is how in drupal way i can get rest of taxonomy fields? In `$form` array is only tids and titles.

Is it possible not to query DB again but setup existing query to retrieve all fields i need?
Also how i can insert that additional information into form? Is it other way than `#suffix` `#prefix` on radios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Drupal 7 then you can use an [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field along with the [Entity Reference view widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) instead of a term reference field. That will allow you to specify a view to use to populate the field options, and you can create an entity reference view that display the additional taxonomy term fields you want to display.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to create a new entity reference for a content object and a taxonomy term when the whole point of a taxonomy term is that it is a referenced object.